# Where are the templates for Visual Studio 2019?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

I downloaded VS 2019 on my Windows 10 machine and I ran into a strange bug where I don't have any templates when I click "Create a new project". I have downloaded "Desktop development with C++", and I expected a template for a console application.

I tried removing and reinstalling VS 2019, but the issue persists. I also tried the "Repair" option.

Edit: The filters are set to "All".

Answer (score 0):

Your filters may be filtering out everything. When you create a new project what are the dropdowns set to below the template search bar? Try clearing them if they aren't set to "All...". If you see a "Clear All" above the project type, click that and see if it's still empty.

Comment: Yes. They all contain the word "All". I feel this is more of a bug on Microsoft's end or some sort of collision on my system.